# How to change the learning rate of an optimizer at any given moment (no LR schedule)?

Tags: python, optimization, neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch

Is it possible in PyTorch to change the learning rate of the optimizer in the middle of training dynamically (I don't want to define a learning rate schedule beforehand)?

So let's say I have an optimizer:

```
optim = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
```

Now due to some tests which I perform during training, I realize my learning rate is too high so I want to change it to say `0.001`. There doesn't seem to be a method `optim.set_lr(0.001)` but is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 176, accepted):

So the learning rate is stored in `optim.param_groups[i]['lr']`.
`optim.param_groups` is a list of the different weight groups which can have different learning rates. Thus, simply doing:

```
for g in optim.param_groups:
    g['lr'] = 0.001
```

will do the trick.

**Alternatively**,

as mentionned in the comments, if your learning rate only depends on the epoch number, you can use a [learning rate scheduler](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#how-to-adjust-learning-rate).

For example (modified example from the doc):

```
torch.optim.lr_scheduler import LambdaLR
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1, momentum=0.9)
# Assuming optimizer has two groups.
lambda_group1 = lambda epoch: epoch // 30
lambda_group2 = lambda epoch: 0.95 ** epoch
scheduler = LambdaLR(optimizer, lr_lambda=[lambda1, lambda2])
for epoch in range(100):
    train(...)
    validate(...)
    scheduler.step()
```

**Also**, there is a [prebuilt learning rate scheduler to reduce on plateaus.](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau.html)

Comment: @MehmetBurakSayıcı ask a new question.

Comment: Use [this automatic updaters](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#how-to-adjust-learning-rate) in 2020

Comment: i tried to use this but i didn't change the lr. 
had to make the change like this:
for i in range(len(optimizer.param_groups)):
    optimizer.param_groups[i]['lr'] = new_lr

Comment: Note that if you use both techniques together, that is you set the learning rate manually and you then use a scheduler, you should not set the `lr` field of the parameter group but the `initial_lr` field (or both). The scheduler uses this to set the `lr` field from, so it'll override any manual changes you make.

Answer (score 20):

Instead of a loop in [patapouf_ai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48324389/4685471), you can do it directly via:

```
optim.param_groups[0]['lr'] = 0.001
```

Comment: This only works if you have a single parameter group. (Which granted is probably most of the time.)

Comment: for some reason this makes model not learn at all

Comment: yeah well cause I did it per batch instead of per epoch, this is rather a confirmation that it works