# Pytorch: Is there a way to implement layer-wise learning rate decay when using a Scheduler?

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to implement the layer-wise learning rate decay while still using a Scheduler.  Specifically, what I currently have is:

```py
model = Model()
optim = optim.Adam(lr=0.1)
scheduler = optim.lr_scheduler.OneCycleLR(optim, max_lr=0.1)
```

Then, the learning rate is increased to `0.1` in the first 30% of the epochs and gradually decays over time. I want to further add this with layer-wise Learning rate decay.

[This tutorial](https://kozodoi.me/python/deep%20learning/pytorch/tutorial/2022/03/29/discriminative-lr.html) is something that I want to implement, but it uses a **fixed LR** instead of changing LR like when used with a Scheduler. What I want is at every step, the model still uses the LR it gets from the optimizer, but then *every layer's LR is also decayed by a factor*. It goes like:

```py
for i in range(steps):
    lr = scheduler.get_last_lr()
    for idx, layer in enumerate(model.layers()):
        layer['lr'] = lr * 0.9 ** (idx+1)
    output = model(input)
    ...
```

However, when using this, do I have to pass the `model.parameters()` to the optimizer again? How will the LR be computed in this scenario? Is there a better way to do this?

Also I am looking for a way to do that for very large models where listing all layers and specifying LRs for each of them is a bit exhaustive.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something that's not a pain vanilla, pytorch-preimplemented schedule for your learning rate, I recommend foregoing the pytorch `scheduler` class and manually adjusting the learning rates for each of the parameter groups yourself. You can directly access the learning rates as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48324152/pytorch-how-to-change-the-learning-rate-of-an-optimizer-at-any-given-moment-no) similar to your code above but accessing the optimizer parameter group handles rather than the model layers directly:

```
for group in optim.param_groups:
    group["lr"] *= 0.9      # for example
```

From here, you can either use a list of decay factors or else a dictionary keyed by the parameter group names to make this concise.